# Calculate residues for this function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to understand the residues.. Here is a simple example I have in my book. But i just can`t understand what author explains there. Is there anybody who can explain me this?
I need to find residues of the next function!
Thank you!

\begin{equation}
z \; \epsilon \; \mathbb{C} \mathbb{-} \{-1,1\}, \\
f(z) = \frac{5z-3}{(z-1)^3(z+1)}
\end{equation}

Comment: There is a simple formula for the residue at $a$ of a function given by something holomorphic divided by $(x-a)^n$.

Comment: @Rasmus: beyond $n=1$, the formula is not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the residue at $z=1$. To that end we need to expand the function as a Laurent series in a neighborhood of that point, i.e. as a series using powers of $(z-1)$. Here we can take the factor $(z-1)^{-3}$ into account in the end, so we need to deal with $g(z)=(5z-3)/(z+1)$. It is holomorphic around $z=1$, so we get a Taylor series.
We see that $g(1)=(5-3)/(1+1)=1$. This suggests that we look at 
$$
g(z)-1=\frac{5z-3}{z+1}-\frac{z+1}{z+1}=\frac{4z-4}{z+1}=\frac4{z+1}(z-1).
$$
So it suffices to expand $h(z)=4/(z+1)$. We continue the same way: $h(1)=2$ and
$$
h(z)-2=\frac4{z+1}-\frac{2(z+1)}{z+1}=\frac{2-2z}{z+1}=\frac{-2}{z+1}(z-1).
$$
At $z=1$ the factor $-2/(z+1)$ takes value $-1$, so we get that
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
h(z)&=&=2-(z-1)+\text{terms with higher powers of $(z-1)$},\\
g(z)&=1+(z-1)h(z)&=1+2(z-1)-(z-1)^2+\text{higher powers},\\
f(z)&=(z-1)^{-3}g(z)&=\frac1{(z-1)^3}+\frac2{(z-1)^2}-\frac1{z-1}+\text{non-negative powers.}
\end{array}
$$
I stopped the expansion process at this point, because we won't be needing the next term. They all became absorbed by that generic "non-negative powers".

The importance of residues comes from the fact that in a compact set, where the Laurent series converges, we can integrate it termwise. Convergence is automatic in an annulus, where the function is holomorphic. Thus along a small circle $\gamma$ looping once counterclockwise around $z=1$ we get
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=\int_\gamma\frac1{(z-1)^3}\,dz+
\int_\gamma\frac2{(z-1)^2}\,dz-\int_\gamma\frac1{z-1}\,dz+\int_\gamma\text{non-negative powers}\,dz.
$$

Now you should recall an earlier exercise telling us that
$$
\int_\gamma(z-1)^n\,dz=\begin{cases}2\pi i,&\text{if $n=-1$,}\\0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

This gives us the neat result
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=\int_\gamma\frac{-1}{z-1}\,dz=-2\pi i.
$$

The residue of $f(z)$ at $z=1$ is that coefficient $-1$ of $(z-1)^{-1}$ in our expansion.

We can calculate the residue at $z=-1$ the same way. It will simpler, because we don't need to calculate so many terms. As alternatives to this process there are generic formulas for the residue. The other answers are using those. To use them you need to first determine the order of the pole your function has at the point of interest. This has hopefully been explained in your book/class shortly before talking about residues.

Comment: Warning: This method for calculating the terms in the Laurent series works fine, because we are working with a rational function. The formula used in other answers has the further benefit that it works more generally.

Answer (score 0):

The function is analytic at all points except $-1,1$ and hence the residues at all points other than these two is zero.

For $-1$, the residue is

$$ \lim\limits_{z\to -1} \frac{5z-3}{(z-1)^{3}} $$

For $1$, the residue is

$$\frac{1}{2!}\lim\limits_{z\to 1}\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}\frac{5z-3}{(z+1)}$$

**EDIT:** I would add some explanation; hope it helps the OP:

Any function has a Laurent series expansion around any point $z_{0}$:

$$ f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^{n} $$

The residue of $f$ at $z_{0}$ is the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in the above expansion. Also, we have the following standard facts:

1. If $f$ is analytic at $z_{0}$ then $a_{-n} = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. If $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{k}}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $g$ is analytic at $z_{0}$, then $a_{n} = 0$ for all $n < -k$.

Now stare at consider your function and look at the point $z_{0} = -1$. Can you see that it fits in case $2$ above? What is your $g$? What is your $k$? After figuring these out, write down the Laurent series expansion of your function $f$.

Now you should be able to make sense of what I did.

Comment: Thank you, but I am so newbie I can`t understand what you used to get this results :)

Comment: For justification, I would point you to any book that contains calculations of residues.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:** If $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $a\in \Bbb C$, then the residue of $f$ at $a$ is $\displaystyle {g^{(n-1)}(a)\over n!},$ where $g=(z-a)^nf(z)$.
Can you prove this theorem? (*Hint:* use Laurent Expansion)
Noting that $f$ has a simple pole at $-1$ and a triple pole at $1$ we get the residues:$$res(f;-1)=\frac {5z-3}{(z-1)^3}\bigg|_{z=-1}=\frac{-8}{(-2)^3}=1$$ and $$res(f;1)=\frac1{2!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{5z-3}{z+1}\bigg|_{z=1}=-1.$$